Building Lineage OS: vendor.qti.gnss@4.0-service.xml These files are not found. Where are they extracted?
FAILED: out/soong/build.lineage_elish.ninja
cd "$(dirname "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && BUILDER="$PWD/$(basename "out/host/linux-x86/bin/soong_build")" && cd / && env -i  "$BUILDER"     --top "$TOP"     --soong_out "out/soong"     --out "out"     --soong_variables out/soong/soong.lineage_elish.variables -o out/soong/build.lineage_elish.ninja --globListDir lineage_elish --globFile out/soong/globs-lineage_elish.ninja -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list --available_env out/soong/soong.environment.available --used_env out/soong/soong.environment.used.lineage_elish.build Android.bp
error: vendor/xiaomi/sm8250-common/Android.bp:273:1: module "vendor.qti.gnss@4.0-service" variant "android_arm64_armv8-a": module source path "vendor/xiaomi/sm8250-common/proprietary/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/vendor.qti.gnss@4.0-service.xml" does not exist
error: vendor/xiaomi/sm8250-common/Android.bp:273:1: module "vendor.qti.gnss@4.0-service" variant "android_arm64_armv8-a": module source path "vendor/xiaomi/sm8250-common/proprietary/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/vendor.qti.gnss@4.0-service.xml" does not exist
error: vendor/xiaomi/sm8250-common/Android.bp:273:1: module "vendor.qti.gnss@4.0-service" variant "android_arm64_armv8-a": module source path "vendor/xiaomi/sm8250-common/proprietary/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/vendor.qti.gnss@4.0-service.xml" does not exist
error: vendor/xiaomi/sm8250-common/Android.bp:273:1: module "vendor.qti.gnss@4.0-service" variant "android_arm64_armv8-a": module source path "vendor/xiaomi/sm8250-common/proprietary/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/vendor.qti.gnss@4.0-service.xml" does not exist
error: vendor/xiaomi/sm8250-common/Android.bp:255:1: module "android.hardware.gnss@2.1-service-qti" variant "android_arm64_armv8-a": module source path "vendor/xiaomi/sm8250-common/proprietary/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hardware.gnss@2.1-service-qti.xml" does not exist
error: vendor/xiaomi/sm8250-common/Android.bp:255:1: module "android.hardware.gnss@2.1-service-qti" variant "android_arm64_armv8-a": module source path "vendor/xiaomi/sm8250-common/proprietary/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hardware.gnss@2.1-service-qti.xml" does not exist
error: vendor/xiaomi/sm8250-common/Android.bp:255:1: module "android.hardware.gnss@2.1-service-qti" variant "android_arm64_armv8-a": module source path "vendor/xiaomi/sm8250-common/proprietary/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hardware.gnss@2.1-service-qti.xml" does not exist
error: vendor/xiaomi/sm8250-common/Android.bp:255:1: module "android.hardware.gnss@2.1-service-qti" variant "android_arm64_armv8-a": module source path "vendor/xiaomi/sm8250-common/proprietary/vendor/etc/vintf/manifest/android.hardware.gnss@2.1-service-qti.xml" does not exist
fatal errors encountered
01:48:40 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
failed to build some targets (37 seconds)
[enter image description here][1]
Where can I get these missing files?
Error when exporting files./extract-files.sh
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/KPbcgoVG.png
